# Using XLSXReader to read an excel file

Tags: excel, graph, acumatica

So, found Sergey Marenich's article on how to read excel using XLSXReader
  e.g. https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/03/reading-excel-file-acumatica.html

I've got a wonderful graph, and a very nice button to "Parse" the file, and have attached the file onto my entity.

When I try to parse the excel, though, I only get the LAST line of the sheet
Data format (very roughly):
  Bunch of junk I don't care about (image, ~10 lines of header fun)
  Several areas I do (I was going to do a match on column A, and if it's a value I want, then use other elements of the row)
  Then more junk I don't care about (a signature image, another 10 lines of summary stuff)

Any ideas?

Very rough graph code:

```
Guid[] files = PXNoteAttribute.GetFileNotes(this.LabResult.Cache, this.LabResult.Cache.Current);
if (files != null && files.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (Guid fileID in files)
    {
        var fm = PXGraph.CreateInstance<PX.SM.UploadFileMaintenance>();
        PX.SM.FileInfo fi = fm.GetFile(fileID);
        if (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Log.LogInfo(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} {1}", "0275b555-9e5b-4b59-8378-991bef88ae62", fi.Name));
        if (fi.Name.ToUpperInvariant().EndsWith(".xlsx".ToUpperInvariant()))
        {
            // Only want Excel files to go through this, since it's excel specific
            Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "138fcfe4-de54-4b9d-8846-43a62123c28a"));
            // Byte[] bytes = fi.BinData;
            using (PX.Data.XLSXReader reader = new XLSXReader(fi.BinData))
            {
                Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "b637b60a-96ce-4a4c-8a42-039cb625f578"));
                //Initialising Reader
                reader.Reset();
                Trace.TraceInformation(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "79abfd64-509d-4d88-89db-c22cd77d45ea"));
                //Creating a dictionary to find column index by name
                //   Dictionary<String, Int32> indexes = reader.IndexKeyPairs.ToDictionary(p => p.Value, p => p.Key);
                //Skipping first row with column names.
                // reader.MoveNext();
                int cntr = 15;
                // while (reader.MoveNext())
                while(cntr-- > 0)
                {
                    reader.MoveNext();
                    if (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Log.LogInfo(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}", "55e32c69-4bed-411a-9fdd-f15d23305c8a"));
                    //Processing row
                    if (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Log.LogInfo(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} '{1}'", "a26f6b05-e942-4d7a-bd32-80ba995549b0", reader.GetValue(RowTypeName)));
                    if (Log.IsInfoEnabled) Log.LogInfo(string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} '{1}' '{2}' '{3}'", "ab31a386-1b3b-4c99-89ba-f10055fd3022", reader.GetValue(1), reader.GetValue(2), reader.GetValue(3)));
```

Lots of comments, using the Guids, that I can verify each element is as desired.
When I tried just movenext, it never entered the loop.  Since I know I have more than 15 lines, tried that
End up with ~15 lines of 
ab31a386-1b3b-4c99-89ba-f10055fd3022 '' 'Last text Line Of File' ''

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything wrong with the reader code. I would try with a different excel file and maybe a different logger.

Comment: Logger is fine, it's built in to .Net, and gives a lot of other info that I've validated in other places

Comment: Excel file also seemed mostly Ok, did try saving as a variety of formats, none did better.  I have NO control over the input file, it's coming from an external source, and even having to open/save as would be pushing it for the end user.  One of the attempts was to "Paste Values" for the entire excel sheet, that just seemed to make things worse

Comment: The built in parser is expecting a format similar to the one produced by the excel export button. First row are column headers followed by cell data.

Comment: Ok.  Any options within this, or I have to use a 3rd party object to get this document parsed?